# Numero de carpetas y archivos por directorio, Java

Tags: java, recursión

Tengo la siguiente función que me calcula la cantidad de directorios y archivos que hay dentro de cada uno (ahora está un poco modificada, pero la idea era esa).

```
public class ComponentCompare {
    
    private static int numDir;
    private static int numFiles;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
 try {
            numDir = 0;
            numFiles = 0;
            recursive(new File("/home/incentivate/Desktop/resources")); // Directorio raíz
            //System.out.println("\nSe han encontrado: " + numDir + " directorios");
            //System.out.println("\nSe han encontrado: " + numFiles + " archivos");
            File salida = new File("./salida.txt");
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(salida));
            bw.write("Se han encontrado: " + numDir + " directorios \n");
            bw.write("Se han encontrado: " + numFiles + " archivos \n");
            bw.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("No existe el archivo de salida!");
        }
     
    } // end del main()



 public static void recursive(File dir) {

        File listFile[] = dir.listFiles();
        File listDir[];
        //System.out.println("Dir:" + dir);
        
        if (listFile != null && listFile.length > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {
                if (listFile[i].isDirectory()){
                    listDir = listFile[i].listFiles();
                    System.out.println("Hay " + listDir.length + " archivos dentro de " + listFile[i].toString());
                    recursive(listFile[i]);
                    numDir++;
                } else if(listFile[i].isFile()){
                    numFiles++;
                }
            }
        }
    } // end de recursive()
```

Que me devuelve esto:

> Hay 6 archivos dentro de /home/incentivate/Desktop/resources/static
>
> Hay 2 archivos dentro de /home/incentivate/Desktop/resources/static/icons
>
> Hay 6 archivos dentro de /home/incentivate/Desktop/resources/static/gifs
>
> Hay 2 archivos dentro de /home/incentivate/Desktop/resources/static/vendor
>
> Hay 5 archivos dentro de /home/incentivate/Desktop/resources/static/vendor/materialize
>
> Hay 2 archivos dentro de /home/incentivate/Desktop/resources/static/vendor/materialize/font
>
> Hay 15 archivos dentro de /home/incentivate/Desktop/resources/static/vendor/materialize/font/roboto
>
> Hay 6 archivos dentro de /home/incentivate/Desktop/resources/static/vendor/materialize/font/material-design-icons
>
> Hay 2 archivos dentro de /home/incentivate/Desktop/resources/static/vendor/materialize/js
>
> Hay 2 archivos dentro de /home/incentivate/Desktop/resources/static/vendor/materialize/css
>
> Hay 1 archivos dentro de /home/incentivate/Desktop/resources/static/vendor/jquery
>
> Hay 5 archivos dentro de /home/incentivate/Desktop/resources/templates

Mi problema es que yo necesito que me diga por cada carpeta a la que entra, que hay dentro de ella ... si hay X cantidad de archivos e Y cantidad de capetas necesito que me liste eso.

Ejemplo:

Entra a la carpeta A ---> Dentro de ésta hay 10 carpetas más y 5 archivos. Que liste esto.

Luego que entre a la carpeta B y me diga exactamente lo mismo y así por cada una.

Ahora mismo me funciona parecido a lo que quiero, pero no exactamente.

Alguien me puede hechar una mano ??

Muchas gracias de antemano !

Saludos a todos

Comment: cual se´ria entonces tu formato de salida esperado?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo primero que se me ocurre (podría haber algo mejor tal vez) que podrías hacer es lo siguiente:

```
public static void recursive(File dir) {

        File listFile[] = dir.listFiles();
        File listDir[];

        if (listFile != null && listFile.length > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {
                if (listFile[i].isDirectory()){
                    listDir = listFile[i].listFiles();
                    files = Arrays.stream(listDir).filter(x -> x.isFile()).toArray();    
                    // Usando filder, optienes el array de archivos

                    System.out.println("Hay " (listDir.length - files.length) + " carpetas y " + files.length + " archivos dentro de " + listFile[i].toString());
                    //La salida seria "Hay xCant carpetas y xCant archivos dentro de xPath"

                    recursive(listFile[i]);
                    numDir++;
                } else if(listFile[i].isFile()){
                    numFiles++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Haciendo uso de `.filter()`, obtienes el *array* de archivos dentro de tu directorio mediante la validación `.isFile()`.

*Asumo que estas usando Java 8+, sino no tendrás el `.filter()`*

Comment: Excelente !!! Es justo lo que necesitaba ! Gratzie Mile